# From the day week number get the day name with Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a *day of the week* number: 2 (which should match to Tuesday if week start on Monday).

From this number is there a way to get the name of the day in Java using Joda Time?
In javascript it has been quite easy to do it using moment.js:

```
moment().day(my number)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Joda-Time

At least this works, although I consider it as not so nice:

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate();
date = date.withDayOfWeek(2);
System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE").print(date));
```

Unfortunately [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) does not offer an enum for the day of week (java.time does). I have not quickly found another way in the huge api. Maybe some Joda-experts know a better solution.

Added (thanks to @BasilBourque):

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate();
date = date.withDayOfWeek(2);
System.out.println(date.dayOfWeek().getAsText());
```

## java.time

In [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), Java 8 and later), use the [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
int day = 2;
System.out.println( DayOfWeek.of(2).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH) );
// Output: Tuesday
```

You can use a particular enum instance directly rather than a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) like `2`. The [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum provides an instance for each day of week such as [`DayOfWeek.TUESDAY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#TUESDAY).

```
System.out.println( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH) );
// Output: Tuesday
```

## Old JDK

For making it complete, here the solution of old JDK:

```
int day = 2;
DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(dfs.getWeekdays()[day % 7 + 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it yourself

```
String[] dayNames = new String[]{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
String name = dayNames[day-1];
```

And this even does not require any library :)

Comment: Yes without library, but not workable in an internationalized scenario. By the way, your solution does not fit to the required index order. The OP wants number 2, your solution would then yield Wednesday instead of Tuesday.

Comment: That covers English. Using Joda-Time gives localization into other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Using Joda you can do this:

```
 DateTime curTime = new DateTime();
 curTime.dayOfWeek().getAsText(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Replace `Locale` with whatever your Locale is.

Should return a week day name such as `Monday or Tuesday`