# Locale-dependent abbreviation of weekdays in Joda-Time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to parse dates. Is there anything to show abbreviations of the weekdays in a specific locale? (eg german: Mo, Di, Mi, Sa...)?

Or how could I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [From the day week number get the day name with Joda Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907809/from-the-day-week-number-get-the-day-name-with-joda-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give the abbreviated day of week:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E.").withLocale(Locale.GERMANY).parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils getDateFormatSymbols provides access to standard java.text.DateFormatSymbols using given locale, use getShortWeekdays method.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#getDateFormatSymbols%28java.util.Locale%29