# Accessing an enum value before it's defined

Tags: java, enums

If I had the enum

```
public enum Days {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY;
}
```

what would be the best way to save the value `TUESDAY` in the value `MONDAY` (for example for use in a method Days#nextDay). I would have thought `MONDAY(TUESDAY)` would have worked, but I cant do this as `TUESDAY` is not yet defined. Is there a workaround for this (for example `MONDAY(Days.valueOf("TUESDAY"))`) or do I need to write a separate method?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't what to use [DayOfWeek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#plus-long-) or it's [joda time analog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907809/from-the-day-week-number-get-the-day-name-with-joda-time)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest and preferred way would be using one of standard classes like [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) introduced in Java 8. You could simply use its [`plus(days)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#plus-long-) method to move to next days like

```
DayOfWeek foo = DayOfWeek.MONDAY.plus(1);//TUESDAY
DayOfWeek bar = DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.plus(1);//MONDAY
```

but if your real problem is about some other enums you can solve it in few ways.

---

One of ways could be letting each Enum instance store its `next` instance. We could set up their value in static block, after all enum values will be already declared:

```
enum Days {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY;

    static{
        MONDAY.next = TUESDAY;
        TUESDAY.next = WEDNESDAY;
        WEDNESDAY.next = THURSDAY;
        THURSDAY.next = FRIDAY;
        FRIDAY.next = SATURDAY;
        SATURDAY.next = SUNDAY;
        SUNDAY.next = MONDAY;
    }

    private Days next;

    public Days nextDay() {
        return next;
    }

}
```

`MONDAY.nextDay()` will return `TUESDAY`.

---

Other way could be simply adding method which will use position of current enum to get next element:

```
enum Days {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY;

    private static final Days[] VALUES = Days.values(); // store result of values()
                                                        // to avoid creating new array
                                                        // each time we use values()
    public Days nextDay() {
        return VALUES[(ordinal() + 1) % 7];
    }

}
```

- `values()` returns array of all values from current enum in order of their declaration
- `ordinal()` returns position of current enum indexed from 0 (0-MONDAY, 1-TUESDAY, and so on).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create an `abstract` method, which is implemented in all the constants. The return value will be the *next day*:

```
public enum Days {
    MONDAY() {
        public Days nextDay() {
            return TUESDAY;
        }
    };
    //TODO: Implement the other days accordingly.

    abstract Days nextDay();
}
```

Comment: A less verbose alternative would be to use the ordinal number in the constructor (instead of an enum instance). But I like this one better.

Comment: I was thinking about this approach, but I picked the `abstract` method one :)

Comment: ... or the name instead of the ordinal, as in @Smutje's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also build a map:

```
public enum Days {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY;

    private static final Map<Days, Days> NEXT = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        NEXT.put(MONDAY, TUESDAY);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Days tuesday = Days.NEXT.get(MONDAY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Days {
    MONDAY("Tuesday"), TUESDAY("Wednesday"), WEDNESDAY("Thursday"), THURSDAY(
            "Friday"), FRIDAY("Saturday"), SATURDAY("Sunday"), SUNDAY(
            "Monday");

    private String day;

    private Days(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getDay(){
        return day;
    }
}
```

I don't know your purpose but this works :-) Else you can use the other answers.

Comment: Works, but it returns `String` instead of `Days`.

Comment: Your method could still return an enum instance, using `valueOf(day)`.