# DateFormat conversion in Android

Tags: java, android, date, days

**Let us suppose we have a date show as.**

```
2015-08-03 12:00:00
```

How would I convert that to a day's name like `Tuesday` ? I don't want things like `03 Tue` etc. Just the full `days` name. I looked around but I am bit confused on that.

Comment: this might help you 
:>)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907809/from-the-day-week-number-get-the-day-name-with-joda-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parse that date into a `java.util.Date` object.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date yourDate = formatter.parse("2015-08-03 12:00:00");
```

Then, populate a `Calendar` with this date:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Now you have your day of week `dayOfWeek` (1 being SUNDAY, for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date now = simpleDateformat.parse("2015-08-03 12:00:00");
 simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); // the day of the week spelled out completely
 System.out.println(simpleDateformat.format(now));
```

Comment: Please stop editing posts to add code formatting everywhere, it's more distracting than anything else, I already had to modify 2 of your edits to make the posts readable again. Thanks.

Comment: Well , those questions more ugly to have a look before my edit .sorry if i did that..

Comment: For example, in the question above, you added code formatting to the words *date* and *days*, but that's not code, so it adds incorrect formatting that attracts the eye to unimportant parts of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd  
       HH:mm:ss");
      Date weekDay = null;
      try {
          weekDay = formatter.parse("2015-08-03 12:00:00");
      } catch (ParseException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
     SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");

     String day = outFormat.format(weekDay);
```