# get day name from string date using jodatime

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I have string date like this

```
String s = "29-08-2016";
```

Desired result is the name of the day of the week:

> Monday

How to resolve that?

Comment: This sounds like it's basically another "parse and reformat" question, where the "output format" is simply the day of week. Have you tried anything so far? What did you try, and what happened? Have you looked at other reformatting questions and tried applying the same techniques, just with your specific format instead?

Comment: check with code in my answer it will work for you.

Comment: i want to find simple method if can using joda lib sir

Comment: Sounds similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907809/from-the-day-week-number-get-the-day-name-with-joda-time). You would just neet to parse the string to a `LocalDate` and then use the link to determine the name of day-of-week.

Comment: Check this answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907809/from-the-day-week-number-get-the-day-name-with-joda-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy takeaway in Joda

```
String date = "29-08-2016";
LocalDate localDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy").parseLocalDate(date);
System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE").print(localDate));
```

prints : Monday

Comment: aha thats elegant method, thanks sir

Answer (score 4):

Without using JODA library, simple java code to get day name of week.

```
String s = "28-08-2016";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy").parse(s);
String dayOfWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
System.out.println(dayOfWeek); // Monday
```

Comment: Why first spilt, then reassemble? Why not parse the original string?

Comment: Now I like it. ;-)

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

First parse the input string into a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

Now interrogate for the day-of-week represented by a [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek();
```

Ask that object to generate a localized name.

```
Locale l = Locale.US;  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH etc.
TextStyle ts = TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE;
String output = ld.getDisplayName( ts , l );
```