# Is it possible in JodaTime to get day of week as a string having only integer number of a day of week without creation of DateTime object

Tags: java, jodatime, date-formatting

I have a primitive int variable with possible values from 1 to 7 (actually it received from calling `getDayOfWeek()` on `org.joda.time.DateTime` object and then persisted).

Now I need to get a string representation of this day of week. I can do it by creating a new `DateTime` object and setting that day of week to created object:

```
LocalDateTime.now().withDayOfWeek(dayOfWeek).dayOfWeek().getAsText();
```

The question is: can I get the same string without redundant creation of a `LocalDateTime` object?

Comment: Yes. The values start with `Monday` as `1`, and end with `Sunday` as `7`. See also [`DateTimeConstants`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html).

Comment: Sorry, there is no better way. By the way, I have found this way in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907809/from-the-day-week-number-get-the-day-name-with-joda-time/20907968#20907968) dated from 2014. The best workaround if you only need English might be just holding a static String-array ("Monday" to "Sunday") and find the string by array index.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I also thought that it was impossible, but I've actually found a way (check my answer below). Anyway, maybe a string array is simpler, if you don't care about a locale sensitive solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve what you want without creating a `LocalDateTime` instance, you can use the `org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology` class to get a `org.joda.time.DateTimeField` that corresponds to the day of week.

In the example below I'm using `org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants`, which has values from Monday (`1`) to Sunday (`7`). I'm also using `java.util.Locale` to get the names in English, but you can use whatever `Locale` you want (**the code in your question [uses the system's default locale](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/field/AbstractReadableInstantFieldProperty.html#getAsText()), in this case you could just use `Locale.getDefault()` instead**):

```
DateTimeField dayOfWeek = ISOChronology.getInstance().dayOfWeek();

System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getAsText(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY, Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getAsText(DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY, Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getAsText(DateTimeConstants.WEDNESDAY, Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getAsText(DateTimeConstants.THURSDAY, Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getAsText(DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY, Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getAsText(DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY, Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getAsText(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY, Locale.ENGLISH));
```

The output is:

> Monday
>   Tuesday
>   Wednesday
>   Thursday
>   Friday
>   Saturday
>   Sunday

---

## New Java Date/Time API

*Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.*

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

```
for(DayOfWeek dow : DayOfWeek.values()) {
    System.out.println(dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

This will also output:

> Monday
>   Tuesday
>   Wednesday
>   Thursday
>   Friday
>   Saturday
>   Sunday

You can also get a `DayOfWeek` from an `int` value - from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday) - using `DayOfWeek.of` method:

```
// 1 is Monday, 2 is Tuesday and so on, until 7 (Sunday)
System.out.println(DayOfWeek.of(1).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));
```

Comment: Hugo, thank you!
I didn't know about this backport and this project is exactly on Android. I'll try to switch to ThreeTen until it's not too late.

Comment: I've migrated the project to ThreeTen and updated all unit tests. All is well.

Comment: @dpg That's great, it's totally worth it! And an eventual migration to java 8 will be much easier as it would require just a package renaming in the imports.

Answer (score 4):

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in maintenance mode, so it is advised to migrate to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. There is a simple and easy solution with `java.time` for your scenario using [DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#of-int-) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) as shown in the example below:

```
int dayOfWeek = 1;
System.out.println(DayOfWeek.of(dayOfWeek)); // prints English all-caps, ex: MONDAY
```

Call [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) to generate a string of the day’s name localized in a human language you specify via a `Locale` object.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable addition @Basil Bourque